# useRef returns always 0 in setInterval in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-ref

### Problem

I am trying to create a component which displays scrolling horizontal text. I am using refs to access the current position of the scrollbar and state to update it. My problem is that the value from the refs is always 0.

### Code

Here is the component:

```
const SiteAlert = () => {
  const [contentWidth, setContentWidth] = React.useState(0);
  const [_currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = React.useState(0);

  const scrollViewRef = React.useRef();
  const currentPositionRef = React.useRef(0);
  const contendWidthRef = React.useRef(contentWidth);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    function handleScroll() {
      const position = currentPositionRef?.current + 5;

      scrollViewRef?.current?.scrollTo({ x: position, animated: true });
      if (position > contendWidthRef.current) {
        scrollViewRef?.current?.scrollTo({ x: 0, animated: true });
        setCurrentPosition(0);
      } else setCurrentPosition(position);
    }

    const activeInterval = setInterval(handleScroll, 400);

    return () => clearInterval(activeInterval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollView
      ref={scrollViewRef}
      horizontal
         bounces
      style={styles.siteAlert}
      onContentSizeChange={width => setContentWidth(width)}
    >
      <Text style={styles.text} numberOfLines={1}>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod in cupiditate, expedita soluta est earum quaerat adipisci fugit, atque, eveniet maxime sint eligendi voluptatem minus dolore et tenetur aliquid totam! Error suscipit aliquam impedit ratione veritatis, placeat sapiente ab consequatur?
      </Text>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

### Thoughts

So what am I doing wrong? I know that because of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), I can't use the state directly in the component, as the value will always be the one from the initial render. What I don't understand is why the refs are not updated. I thought they would always have the current value. I created a [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pascalneocosmo/sitealert-demo) for people to check out.

Comment: I think you can only set ref on a html tag. It seems that you are setting it on ScrollView component. What is this component? Is the ref passed to a div?

Comment: It is a React Native app. ScrollView is a scrollable container, the app equivalent of a div.

Comment: If passed to a component it becomes prop ... 

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with that or how it is related to the problem.

Comment: sorry, I was just adding the point to szczoick's reply ...

Comment: No problem, I just got confused by the comment. Thanks for the taking the time trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you haven't update `const currentPositionRef = React.useRef(0);` this ref anywhere, you have setCurrentPosition method, but it updates state, not ref.

The second thing, in that case `const contendWidthRef = React.useRef(contentWidth);` I'm not sure if refs working this way, but you don't need ref here at all, cause you can simply take data from contentWidth state itself.

Hope that first paragraph answered your question about why it's always 0

Comment: Yes, it only updates the state. But the ref contains a reference to the state. So the ref should always have the current value of the state. I don't use the state directly, because it will get stale because of the closure I do in the `useEffect` hook.